# Inserting data from session using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I'm just practicing using session in Codeigniter and i've got a Problem here's my controller

```
public function ajax_Addfees()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
      $input = $this->input->post();
      if($this->session->userdata('html')){
        $html = $this->session->userdata('html');
    }
      $id = explode($input['fno']);
      $html[$id] = ['amount' => $input['amount'], 'oldamount' => $input['deduction']];

      $this->session->set_userdata('html', $html);
    }
}

public function savetuition()
{                        
    $this->Tuition_model->savefees();       
    redirect('tuitionsetup_con');    
}
```

This is my model

```
public function savefees() 
{  
    $fees = $this->session->userdata('html');
    $feeslist = [];
    if( !empty($fees) ) {
    foreach ($fees as $key =>$value) {
            array_push($feeslist, [
            'amount' => $value['amount'],
            'oldamount' => $value['oldamount'],
            'f_no' => $key,
            'sy_no' => $this->session->userdata('sy'),
            'level_no' => $this->session->userdata('lvl'),
            'id' => $this->session->userdata('id')
        ]);
        $this->db->insert_batch('tuition', $feeslist);
    } }

}
```

Well what I'm trying to do is to save data from session->set_userdata('html') to my database using codeigniter.

There's no error but it doesn't save data to database

Comment: what do you get on var_dump($feeslist) ?? \

Comment: passing data from $fees to $feeslist. Sorry I'm just new in codeigniter.

Comment: your insert query is outside foreach loop. And is `$fees` an array? post what you get from `var_dump($fees);`

Comment: I put it inside i got no error but it doesn't save any data

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your model as:

```
public function savefees() { 

   $fees = $this->session->userdata('html'); 
   $feeslist = array(); 
   if( !empty($fees) ) { 
      foreach ($fees as $key =>$value) {
        $feeslist[$key]["amount"] = $value['amount'];
        $feeslist[$key]["oldamount"] = $value['oldamount'];
        $feeslist[$key]["f_no"] = $key;
        $feeslist[$key]["sy_no"] = $this->session->userdata('sy');
        $feeslist[$key]["level_no"] = $this->session->userdata('lvl') ;
        $feeslist[$key]["id"] = $this->session->userdata('id') ;
      }
   }
   $this->db->insert_batch('tuition', $feeslist);
}
```